# How to find average of values in file with JSON-like format?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am currently recording latency of some write requests to the database just as a part of my internship. There are literally thousands of values like this that gets saved locally in a file named `latency.json` (I know this is not correct JSON format), but anyways my question is I just need to find the average value of these, and I am supposed to write a python program for this and I have no idea because I am very very new to python.

I watched a few videos to but it is not helpful because I don't know how to isolate only the latency value.

```
{"Latency": 0.05749578899849439, "Date & Time": "2021-03-10T20:50:07.132809"}
{"Latency": 0.03988014299829956, "Date & Time": "2021-03-10T20:50:07.673860"}
{"Latency": 0.055852558005426545, "Date & Time": "2021-03-10T20:50:08.230857"}
{"Latency": 0.04969122799957404, "Date & Time": "2021-03-10T20:50:08.781738"}
{"Latency": 0.04796638499828987, "Date & Time": "2021-03-10T20:50:09.330938"}
{"Latency": 0.043185365000681486, "Date & Time": "2021-03-10T20:50:10.022725"}
{"Latency": 0.0398543819974293, "Date & Time": "2021-03-10T20:50:10.563757"}
```

Comment: Are the lines you pasted in an array in the json? If so, you should be able to use something like `sum([req["Latency"] for req in requests])/len(requests)` if you load them into a list with `json.load`.

Comment: The format is called [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/), You can process it in Python by reading each line of the file and passing it to `json.loads()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format is `JSON Lines` then you might want to try this:

```py
import json

with open("lines.jsonl") as lines:
    d = [json.loads(line) for line in lines.readlines()]
    print(f"Average for {len(d)} requests: {sum(i['Latency'] for i in d) / len(d)}")
```

Output:

```
Average for 7 requests: 0.04770369285688503
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple approach should work:

```
import json

s = 0
n = 0
for line in open('data_file.dat'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line == "":
        continue
    d = json.loads(line)
    n += 1
    s += d["Latency"]

print(s/n)
```